# In need of help using /testfor command

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to test if there is a sheep at location -155 7 14. Im a begginer and have little to no clue to what I'm doing. I dont know how to format anything in minecraft command blocks like when to use !,=,@,[,] etc. If there is no sheep there I want the code to detect it and thus carry on a different command, vise versa. How should I format this?

Comment: Please do some research next time before posting a question. The [Minecraft Wiki's page on `/testfor`](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands/testfor) should do you well in helping you learn the basics of commands. Also check out their [page on target selectors](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands#Target_selectors).

Answer (score 1):

```
/testfor @e[type=sheep,x=-155,y=7,z=14,r=1]
```

- `type=sheep` - Look for a sheep.
- `x=-155`..`y=`..`z=`... - Start search at these coordinates
- `r=1` - Look in a radius of 1 block

Comment: I tried that but it keeps on saying "No targets matched selector." Does this mean it's false? (as in there is no sheep there)

Comment: It's resolved! I didn't need the command block and replaced it with a redstone circut that works.

Comment: Very good explanation! I replaced metre with block because not everyone is clear about 1m being one block.